# Формирование документа Word в оперативной памяти в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Добрый день!

Формирую вордовский документ в ASP.NET приложении из шаблона путем подстановки полей через библиотеку `OpenXMLPowerTools`. Шаблон содержит 1 лист, итоговый документ должен содержать порядка 850 листов.

При использовании библиотеки `OpenXMLPowerTools` в строке формирования документа  `WmlDocument resultDocument= DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources)` (source - это `List<Source>` соответственно с 850 объектами) выпадает `OutOfMemoryException` (на машине 4 Гб), сам итоговый документ будет весить порядка 4 Мб.

Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: А в Visual Studio в профилировщике не смотрели сколько памяти он сжирает?